# stop gracefully and wait till previous pipeline ends in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have a pipe line that is built by many `stage`s and `post`

```
stage ('testEnvDeploy')
...
...
stage ('testA') ...
stage ('testB') ...
stage ('testC') ...
post { 
   always {
      //destroy what first stage (testEnvDeploy) deployed
   }
}
```

`Deploy stage` must run after our `destroy` finished - unless it is running for the first time.

Deploy and destroy are tasks that start a process. Killing the stage won't stop the deployment, or the destroy.

Every push made, I would like to jump over the TEST stages so we won't have to wait or let Jenkins work hard but I **do not** want to touch the deploy or destroy.

which means if deploy started we need to wait till it ends.. If destroy started the next pipeline deploy stage should wait as well.

we have added this option

```
options {
   disableConcurrentBuilds(abortPrevious: true)
}
```

but this making us wait till the previous job ends.

Then we changed it to false

```
options {
   disableConcurrentBuilds(abortPrevious: false)
}
```

And now the previous job jumped and run the `post` and the new pipeline started the deploy already - parallel to the destroy of the previous pipeline.

Is it possible to synchronized between the pipelines and get what we want to achieve ?

Another question is, is it possible when a pipeline is aborted to let the current running step finish properly and not killing it?

Answer (score 0):

pipeline means : a linear sequence of specialized modules used for pipelining.
also the aim of test is to not deploy bad integrated code, you must pass and then deploy.
if you don't like tests, just comment them.

The **given then** methodology of devops rapid deploy is based on test pass ,in your case you just need continuous deployment options rather than integration.
Continuous integration puts a great emphasis on testing automation to check that the application is not broken whenever new commits are integrated into the main branch.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. Maybe I was unclear. The deploy and destroy are the creating/destroying of the test environment.. and not deploy of the code. But when I think about it again (Thanks to you) I could add the number of the build to my test environment and each build will have its own clean environment.. Make sense, or ?

Comment: For now i've just added another unique value to the name of the test environment because I didn't find a away to sync between the end of the previous job to the new one..